# Algorithm to find Articulation points in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I know how to find Articulation points for a undirected graph using DFS variant. But it seems like it is for undirected graph and only looks for back edge. But how to find Articulation points if my graph has forward edge or cross edge.I know i can always run dfs for every node and figure that out but is there any better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Definition for Articulation points on directed graph is not unique.
It depends on what kind of connectedness you are considering. There are 3 kind of connections in directed graph

**Strongly connected** if there is a path from every vertex to every other vertex.

**Connected** if there is a path between any two nodes, but not in both directions.

**Weakly connected** if the graph is only connected if the arcs are replaced with undirected arcs.

If you are using second definition of connection, then U can use DFS for finding points.

I am not sure, but I think that if you define connection as **Weakly connected** then you can use DFS too. But it need to be proved.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that the definition of articulation is not as clear as in case of undirected graphs. However if we choose two particular nodes: source and sink and call any point that must occur on the path from source to sink articulation point, the definition is clear.

I call them unavoidable points and have got simple solution for finding them on my [GitHub](https://github.com/vSzemkel/CppStuff/blob/9d14d39e8f3f8c20729a27b91c4393801780ac37/classic/digraph.cpp#L75)